# Why does SVN 1.7 show on my mac (Mavericks)

Tags: terminal, svn, path, osx-mavericks

I have installed SVN 1.8 on my mac (Mavericks) in /usr/local but when I do svn --version it still shows 1.7, I have added "export PATH=/usr/local:/usr/bin:$PATH" to "~/.bash_profile" and also loaded it with "source ~/.bash_profile"

What am I missing?

Comment: You should probably be adding `/usr/local/bin` to `PATH` instead of `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Already tried that too